# C++ different results when using reduce with std::execution::par

Tags: c++, reduce

I am trying to read a huge file (~ 1 GB) and counting the line breaks in there. So, I tried to use `std::reduce` with parallel execution policy to speed things up. For some reason though, `std::reduce` gives me wrong results when I use it in combination with `std::execution::par` or `std::execution::par_unseq`.

The test code:

```
std::vector<char> file_data(static_cast<U32>(sz));
stream.read(file_data.data(), static_cast<U32>(sz));
    
const auto lines_count = std::reduce(
        std::execution::seq,
        file_data.begin(),
        file_data.end(),
        0u,
        [](const U32 curr, const char ch) { return curr + (ch == '\n'); });

    
const auto lines_count2 = std::reduce(
        std::execution::par,
        file_data.begin(),
        file_data.end(),
        0u,
        [](const U32 curr, const char ch) { return curr + (ch == '\n'); });

const auto lines_count3 = std::reduce(
        std::execution::par_unseq,
        file_data.begin(),
        file_data.end(),
        0u,
        [](const U32 curr, const char ch) { return curr + (ch == '\n'); });

const auto lines_count4 = std::reduce(
        std::execution::unseq,
        file_data.begin(),
        file_data.end(),
        0u,
        [](const U32 curr, const char ch) { return curr + (ch == '\n'); });

const auto lines_count5 = GetLinesCnt(threads_num, static_cast<U32>(sz), file_data);
```

`GetLinesCnt` is a routine I parallized manually. Its code:

```
[[nodiscard]] static U32
GetLinesCnt(
    const U32 threads_num,
    const U32 sz,
    const std::vector<char>& file_data)
{
    std::vector<std::future<U32>> res;
    res.reserve(threads_num);
    for (auto i= 0u; i <threads_num; ++i)
    {
        res.push_back(std::async(
            [i, &file_data, sz, threads_num]
            {
                const auto beg = file_data.begin() + static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(i * sz / threads_num);
                const auto end = (i == threads_num - 1) 
                    ? file_data.end()
                    : file_data.begin() + static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>((i + 1) * sz / threads_num);
                return std::accumulate(beg,end, 0u,
                    [](const U32 curr, const char ch) -> U32
                    { return curr + (ch == '\n'); });
            }));
    }
    return std::accumulate(res.begin(), res.end(), U32{}, [](auto curr, auto& fut) {return curr + fut.get();});
}
```

The results:
[image: results]

As far as I can see, there are no data races. So, any ideas why the results are different? I am using MSVC with C++20.

Comment: Looks to me like your `binary_op` lambda is non-commutative (you are using the input `curr` to determine the output. So, the order of evaluation matters. I think. Can't prove it (yet) though. However, if that *is* the case, then the behaviour is non-deterministic and would most likely fail for parallel execution. (Possibly, though this comment is *utterly* off-the-mark?)

Comment: ... I *think* the answer to [this possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64912315/10871073) agrees with my diagnosis.

Comment: `i * sz / threads_num` - If sz is 1GB and threads_num is say `8`, how does that expression not generate overflow on a 32-bit process?  Or even on a 64-bit process for that matter given that `i*sz` will overflow.  Consider saying: `i * (sz/threads_num)`

Comment: @selbie The file I am using In the test code is only 100MB. In the actual code I am using U64 ~ uint64_t

Comment: I agree with @AdrianMole, this appears to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64912315/using-binaryop-within-stdreduce-from-numeric-with-parallel-execution-polic). Voting to close.

Comment: @bnaecker yes, this was pretty much the problem.

Comment: @modanashar Excellent! Maybe close your question, linking to the duplicate that solved the issue?